# Abrir pagina web con app en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo una duda sobre una app que me solicitaron,  en mi trabajo tienen una pagina web que contiene videos para reproduccion automatica, lo que debo hacer con mi app es ingresar a esa pagina en modo pantalla completa. Eso ya lo realice y probe y funciona sin problemas, pero al instalar la apk en un celular para hacer las pruebas, me abre la pagina deseada y me abre el navegador del celular tambien, y al ocurrir eso la pagina en mi app me redirige a la raiz de la pagina (la pagina es http://172.16.10.3/slider y me regresa a http://172.16.10.3). Este es el codigo de mi app :

```
package com.example.serverssupport.myapplication;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView web = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(web);
    web.loadUrl("http://172.16.10.3/slider");

}

}
```

Hay algo mal en el codigo para que ocurra eso? como podria evitarlo?
Agradeciendo de antemano su apoyo me despido.

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez solo necesitas agregar esto:

...

```
 String url = "http://172.16.10.3/slider";
```

...

```
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
        }
    });
```

Así podrás navegar por toda tu página web sin que te redirigía al navegador por defecto del teléfono y se mantenga siempre dentro de tu aplicación.